# SQL Server memory optimized tables detecting concurrency violation

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables, in-memory-oltp

In SQL Server memory optimized tables, the `rowversion` data type is not allowed.

In my application I still want to be able to detect a concurrency violation where user A opens an item for edit, User B opens the same item, User A saves and User B saves without seeing user A's changes. I've used a `rowversion` column for this for years. What's the recommendation for managing my own fake `rowversion` column?

Comment: How about using your own identity column for this purpose?

Comment: Extend your WHERE clause so that all the old values are passed in also. If the update affects 0 rows the row must have been changed by another client since your download of the "old" values

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what frontend language you use, but here's a tip from my experience with c#'s datasets and the "use optimistic concurrency" option

When you download a row into a DataTable, the dt tracks the original values it downloaded:

```
SELECT id, name, age, address FROM person

--> 1, Jon, 33, null
```

You make an update:

```
dt[0].Name = "Paul"
```

The row now tracks two values, original (Jon) and current (Paul)

Sending the update back to the database, it runs a query like this:

```
UPDATE person 
SET name = @currentName 
WHERE id = @originalID and 
 (Name = @originalName or (@originalName is null AND name is null)) AND 
 ...
```

So effectively:

```
UPDATE person 
SET name = 'Paul'
WHERE id = 1 and 
 (Name = 'John' or ('John' is null AND name is null)) AND...
```

This way data that has been changed/nulled/nonnulled by a foreign client can be detected

It may be simplest to use an ORM for your language, that has this facility

-

ps: Perhaps a simpler notion for this is to add an int column and a trigger to increment it. It probably doesn't sit well with most people though, to add a column that is purely for information control in this manner, rather than modelling some real world data aspect of the stored entity

Comment: An alternative to the int column is a simple datetime2 column that records the date & time when the row was changed (or created). Slightly more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The Memory-Optimized table subsystem has built-in support for optimistic concurrency.

[Transactions with Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transactions-with-memory-optimized-tables)

> Error Code: 41302
>
> Description: Attempted to update a row that was
>   updated in a different transaction since the start of the present
>   transaction.
>
> Cause: This error condition occurs if two concurrent
>   transactions attempt to update or delete the same row at the same
>   time. One of the two transactions receives this error message and will
>   need to be retried.

For other scenarios, such as the "Open customer account in CRM" situation, you can still use the old-school ways, like having a manually-applied row version number, that you stick into your predicates.

For instance:

```
UPDATE
 [MyTable]
SET
 [Col001] = 'SomeVal'
WHERE
 PK = @primaryKey
 AND [RowVersionColumn] = @rowVersionStashedFromSelect
```